# How to use webapp2.uri_for in a template?

Tags: google-app-engine, django-templates, webapp2

webapp2 says [webapp2.uri_for](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.uri_for) is a "standalone uri_for version that can be passed to templates."  Sounds perfect.  When I pass it to the Django template renderer as follows:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
self.response.out.write(template.render(path,
    { 'webapp2': webapp2 }))
```

and put this in the template

```
Please <a href="{{ webapp2.uri_for('contact') }}">send us 
your feedback</a>.
```

app engine 1.7.0 says

> TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '('contact')' from 'webapp2.uri_for('contact')'

If I put instead

```
Please <a href="{{ webapp2 }}">send us your feedback</a>.
```

it shows

> module%20%27webapp2%27%20from%20%27/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.pyc%27%

so I know webapp2 is getting into the template.

How do I get this thing to work?

Comment: perhaps set it as a global as jinja2 (the way I know) does? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081250/webapp2-jinja2-how-can-i-get-uri-for-working-in-jinja2-views

Answer (score -1):

`google.appengine.ext.webapp.template` is a django template, yet your template markup examples are taken from Jinja2.

See this page for an example usage of webapp2 + Jinja2:
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html

Once you managed rendering a simple template, add `'uri_for': webapp2.uri_for` to the context or, better yet, add it to jinja2 globals.

So, for a Django template, as a primitive example, you could create a simple tag:

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(name='uri_for')
def webapp2_uri_for(route_name):
    return webapp2.uri_for(route_name)
```

and then use it in your templates like this:

```
{% uri_for 'contact' %}
```

See this for details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: No, that's a Django template.  Django and Jinja are pretty close but not the same.

Comment: You don't do function calls with parameters in Django like you did in your example `{{ webapp2.uri_for('contact') }}`, hence my assumption (that you wanted to use Jinja2 templates instead).

Comment: If you want to use webapp2.uri_for in a Django template then what you need is probably create a custom tag, very similar to the built-in `url`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url